Coordinate-free definition of grades in Clifford algebra
Consider the Clifford algebra $\operatorname{Cl}(V, Q)$ of some real vector space with a non-degenerate quadratic form. Pick any orthogonal basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$. We define grade-k elements as the linear span of products of k distinct basis vectors from $\{e_i\}$.
Clearly, the Clifford algebra is the direct sum of grade-k subspaces for $k\in 0\dots\dim V$. Also, these subspaces don't actually depend on the chosen basis, as long as it is orthogonal.
What bothers me is that it seems like there should be a cleaner, coordinate-free way to define these subspaces, and my question is whether such a definition exists?

My thoughts:
There are two nice automorphisms of the Clifford algebra that can help us distinguish different grades.
First, there is $\alpha$ defined on vectors by $\alpha(v) = -v$ and extended to the full algebra. It preserves the even part (i.e. even-grade elements) and negates the odd part.
Then, there is the transposition antiautomorphism $(\cdot)^t$ defined on arbitrary products of vectors as $(v_1v_2\dots v_n)^t = v_n\dots v_2v_1$ and extended by linearity. On products of k vectors of an orthogonal basis it is equivalent to multiplication by $(-1)^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}$. This operation preserves grade-0 and grade-1, negates grade-2 and grade-3, and then continues like that with a period of 4.
Thus, we get the following table:



Grade
$\alpha$
$(\cdot)^t$




0
+
+


1
-
+


2
+
-


3
-
-


4
+
+



These two operations alone let us distinguish all grades in a 3D space, but they're not enough in 4D, where grade-4 is invariant under both $\alpha$ and $(\cdot)^t$.
Curiously, these two operations themselves don't use the geometric structure of the space (i.e. the quadratic form), they just happen to factor through the ideal that defined the Clifford algebra as a quotient of the tensor algebra $T(V)$. It would be fun to find another involution with a period of 8 that probably has to use the quadratic form somehow.

$
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
\newcommand\Ext{\mathop{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\lintr{\mathbin\lrcorner}
$This is equivalent to a linear isomorphism with the exterior algebra (which of course has the $\mathbb Z$-grading we want).
To that end, in $\Cl(V,Q)$ define an operation $V\times\Cl(V,Q)\to\Cl(V,Q)$ by
$$
  v\wedge X := \frac12(vX + \alpha(X)v).
$$
Then $v\wedge(v\wedge X) = 0$ so the map $v\mapsto (v\wedge{-}) : V \to \mathrm{End}(\Cl(V,Q))$ extends to an algebra homomorphism $\psi : \Ext V \to \mathrm{End}(\Cl(V,Q))$. Then $\psi({-})(1) : \Ext V \to \Cl(V,Q)$ can be proven to be a linear isomorphism, and we use this to construct the notion of "grade" in $\Cl(V,Q)$.
This is a general phenomenon in Clifford algebras, called the deformation of $\Cl(V,Q)$ by a (not necessarily symmetric) bilinear form $\beta$:
$$
  \Cl(V,Q) \cong \Cl(V,Q+\beta)
$$
where the isomorphism is only linear and $(Q+\beta)(v) = Q(v) + \beta(v,v)$. Note that $\Ext V = \Cl(V, 0)$. These are known as the Chevalley maps. This can be understood using the above isomorphism with $\Ext V$, though a more "direct" (but more involved) understanding is possible. See chapter 4 of Quadratic Mappings and Clifford Algebras by Jacques Helmstetter and Artibano Micali, particularly section 4.7; or see these notes by Darij Grinberg for an approach descending from the tensor algebra.
It is perhaps instructive to show the case $\Cl(V, \beta) \to \Ext V$ as well. We make use of the (left) interior product $\lintr : V^* \times \Ext V \to \Ext V$. Define a product $V\times\Ext V \to \Ext V$ by
$$
  v\bullet X := \beta(v,{-})\lintr X + v\wedge X.
$$
Then $v\bullet(v\bullet X) = \beta(v,v)X$ so the map $v \mapsto (v\bullet{-})$ extends to an algebra homomorphism $\phi : \Cl(V, \beta) \to \mathrm{End}(\Ext V)$. Then $\phi({-})(1) : \Cl(V, \beta) \to \Ext V$ can be proven to be the desired linear isomorphism, in fact the inverse of $\psi({-})(1)$.

Thank you, this sounds like exactly what I needed. I'll digest the answer and then accept it.

Am I correct that under this map $\psi(-)(1)$ the k-vector $v_1\wedge \dots \wedge v_k$ doesn't map to the way k-vectors are usually defined in Clifford algebras, i.e. $\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{\sigma\in S_k} (-1)^{\deg \sigma} v_{\sigma(1)}\cdots v_{\sigma(k)}$ ? In particular, for $\psi(v_1\wedge v_2 \wedge v_3)(1)$ we get $\frac{1}{4}(v_1v_2v_3-v_1v_3v_2+v_2v_3v_1-v_3v_2v_1)$, while with the other formula we should get 6 terms.

No, they are exactly the same. It is just maybe not obvious at first. It is enough that the definitions agree on a basis, and it is clear that they do agree if we choose an orthogonal basis.

In a little more detail, we have two linear maps $\Psi,\Psi' : {\bigwedge V}\to\mathrm{Cl}(V,Q)$ where $\Psi(X) = \psi(X)(1)$ and $\Psi'$ is given by antisymmetrization. If $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$ is an orthogonal basis for $V$, then for any $E = e_{i_1}\wedge\dotsb\wedge e_{i_k}$ with $i_1<\dotsb<i_k$ we see that $\Psi(E) = e_{i_1}\dotsb e_{i_k} = \Psi'(E)$. Of course all such $E$ forms a basis for ${\bigwedge V}$, thus $\Psi = \Psi'$.

What you're seeing is that there are two different factorings through the tensor algebra ${\bigwedge V} \to {\bigotimes V} \overset\pi\to \mathrm{Cl}(V, Q)$ for the same map via the natural projection $\pi$. These factorings are "unnatural" in that they don't exist in positive characteristic, whereas the total map $\Psi$ always exists and is uniquely determined if the characteristic is not 2.

Oh, I see, thank you so much!

This is probably not what you are looking for morally; but it is technically coordinate free.
Define a $k$-blade as any product of $k$ orthogonal vectors (they do not need to be normalized).
A $k$-vector is any element that is the sum of $k$-blades.

I agree that technically it's coordinate free, but we still need to prove that different grades don't intersect, though, and I don't know a way to do that without resorting to explicit computations in an orthogonal basis.

@lisyarus If you want to go this route, here is an option: First, let $$\langle X\rangle = \frac1{2^{\dim V}}\mathrm{tr}(Y \mapsto XY).$$ This is an intrinsic definition of the scalar part in $\mathrm{Cl}(V, Q)$. You can prove that $(X, Y) \mapsto \langle XY\rangle$ is a nondegenerate bilinear form. Then say that $X$ is a $k$-vector if for all $j$-blades $Y$ (as defined above) with $j\ne k$ we have $\langle XY\rangle = 0$.

Now, if $X$ is both a $k$-vector and $j$-vector for $k\ne j$ then $\langle XY\rangle = 0$ for all blades $Y$; it is now enough to simply appeal to the existence of a basis of blades for the algebra to conclude that $X = 0$.

An important observation in my opinion is that even though $Cl(V,Q)$ is not an $\mathbb{N}$-graded algebra (or $\mathbb{Z}$-graded as people often prefer), it is $\mathbb{N}$-filtered: the filtering $T(V)_{\leqslant k}=\bigoplus_{i\leqslant k} V^{\otimes i}$ of the tensor algebra of $V$ factors through $Cl(V,Q)$, and basically $Cl_{\leqslant k}(V,Q)$ is the subsapce of $Cl(V,Q)$ generated by products $v_1\cdots v_i$ with $i\leqslant k$. (The fact that it is a filtered algebra means that
$$Cl_{\leqslant n}(V,Q)\cdot Cl_{\leqslant m}(V,Q)\subset Cl_{\leqslant n+m}(V,Q).$$
Another piece of structure that $Cl(V,Q)$ has is a canonical (nondegenerate) bilinear form. Recall that $Cl(V,Q)$ is a central simple algebra, whose center $Z$ is the base field $K$ when $V$ is odd-dimensional, and a quadratic étale extension $Z/K$ when $V$ is even-dimensional. (When $\dim(V)$ is even and the discriminant of $Q$ is trivial, then $Z\simeq K\times K$, so $Cl(V,Q)$ is not truly simple as a ring, but it is still an Azumaya algebra over $Z$.) Therefore it has a reduced trace $Trd: Cl(V,Q)\to Z$, and we can compose it further with the trace $Tr_{Z/K}: Z\to K$ (which is the identity when $Z=K$) to get an "extended trace" $Trd_{/K}: Cl(V,Q)\to K$ (this is not canonical notation but I'm not sure there is one). Then the canonical symmetric bilinear form is the trace form
$$ T:(x,y)\mapsto Trd_{/K}(xy)\in K.$$
The canonical $\mathbb{N}$-grading of $Cl(V,Q)$ as a vector space that you are looking for can be defined as: $Cl_k(V,Q)$ is the orthogonal complement of $Cl_{\leqslant k-1}(V,Q)$ in $Cl_{\leqslant k}(V,Q)$ for the trace form.

That's a very interesting perspective, thank you!

This is great. If I understand correctly this is very nearly the same as my comment under G. Bellaard's answer. Do you have a favorite reference that covers these "reduced traces"?

@NicholasTodoroff Indeed it is entirely in the same spirit, with the addition of the canonical filtering. Actually in this case there is no real need to go to the "reduced trace", I just mentioned it by reflex. Any book on central simple algebras will cover reduced traces, for instance Gille and Szamuely's "Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology". In general $Trd_A = n\dot Tr_A$ where $n$ is the degree of the central simple algebra ($n=\sqrt{\dim(A)}$), which can matter in positive characteristic, but here $n$ is a power of $2$ and the characteristic is not $2$, so it's not so relevant.
